# httparty not working with localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am making `rails` app which contain APIs and I want my controllers to call that APIs instead of dealing with `ActiveRecord`.

I am using `HTTParty` for making calls. When I do the following it is working fine.

```
response = HTTParty.get('https://google.com')
```

But when I try for my API call it keeps on processing status as the browser is sending request even I waited for 15 minutes but it rendered nothing and I saw the rails console but there was no sign of any request.

For my API call I am using this:

```
response = HTTParty.get('http://localhost:3000/api/v1/score_sheets/9')
```

even I tried this:

```
response = HTTParty.get('http://0.0.0.0:3000/api/v1/score_sheets/9')
```

And this also:

```
response = HTTParty.get('http://127.0.0.1:3000/api/v1/score_sheets/9')
```

Making direct request through browser `https://localhost:3000/api/v1/score_sheets/9` this returns the right `JSON`.

**Problem:** What is wrong with sending request to the localhost using this method? or any other possible way of doing this?

Answer (score 2):

In development mode, one instance of your app processes one request at a time (in production, as of rails 4, thread safe mode is enabled by default however depending on how the app is deployed  this may have no effect). More precisely, the Rack::Lock middleware only let's through one request at a time, so this affects everything below that middleware

If another request arrives while a request is still being processed then it must wait for the first one to complete. In your case this results in your code waiting for ever: the httparty request can only complete when the current request has completed, but that can only happen when the httparty request has completed.

There is more than one way to deal with this, for example:

- you could run multiple instances of your app (this is easy with tools such as pow or passenger)
- you could split your app into 2 so that the api is provided by a separate app

Answer (score 1):

If you are in **development** environment (using like WEBrick or thin as the server), then it could only handle **one request at a time**.

***A single Rails process could only handle one request at a time.***

So the request made by `HTTParty` will be blocked.

Comment: at one time I am sending only one request.

Comment: @G.B You make a request and tell rails to make another request, then the another request would be blocked.

Comment: oh. ok got it. but how to handle this thing ?

Comment: @G.B In the same application you don't need to communicate with http protocal.

Comment: So what If I want to call that api kept in file app/api/v1/score_sheets ? means how to request for api and get the response?